# How to allow/force page-break for printing of <iframe ....> elements embedded in web page?

Tags: css

Sometimes I have web pages with one or more longer embedded `<iframe>` elements.

When  I print them (into PDF file) then the `<iframe>` part(s) are currently NEVER cut at pdf page end. Instead the beginning of the `<iframe>` content is shifted to the top of the next pdf page.

How can I allow (or better: force) the print engine to always start the print of the `<iframe>` element content on the current pdf page, cut `<iframe>` element content if necessary and resume print of the remaining part on the following pdf page?

Comment: So you need an example. Here it is (from a german online magazine):

https://www.techstage.de/bestenliste/top-10-usb-c-ladegeraete-ab-65-watt-fuer-tablet-und-laptop-guenstig-schlaegt-teuer/n8ysw09

Pay attention to all sections with caption: "heise preisvergleich"

Comment: did you ever find an answer? I'm looking for an answer and have found your posts on like half a dozen different forums

Comment: @Nick Hanson: No sorry, sad but true: the page-break seems to be limited. Possibly there is another way but It didn't found it yet.